# Use L1 feature selection when L2 is better fit?

Tags: logistic, regularization

I've run L1 and L2 logistic regression models on my (very large) data and L2 is notably better at ROCAUC. However, depending on the parameters (regularization, class weight) the feature coefficients vary a lot and I'm not sure which features are most relevant for a better performing model.

Does it make sense to use the L1 regularization coefficient results to select top features, despite L1 being worse on the test scores?

I could retrain the selected features with L2.

Comment: How much is notably better? Is the difference distinguishable from the standard error of the cross-validation scores?

Comment: Yes, the difference is beyond the error. Both are actually not very good (L2 AUC 0.66, L1 AUC 0.56). I wanted a starting point for feature selection.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, so I submit it as a comment: Have you considered elastic net regression, which combines the L1 and L2 models and allows you to tune a parameter that mixes them together? This is available in the glmnet package for R and I believe it is also implemented somewhere in sklearn, with which I am quite unfamiliar. I ask because part of your question applies to the uncertainty in whether the L1 or L2 norm is appropriate. Perhaps some principled combination could do better than both alone.

Comment: Yes, elasticnet is also a parameter in sklearn. I believe the few parameter tests I did, indicated that rather extreme L1 or L2 is better. I'd also like to mention that I do SGD training on batches, which might introduce effects.